# Flexbox with h2 and button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am pretty new to React.js and flexbox, and I currently have a flexbox with both an h2 and a button that I want to center. Unfortunately, even when I put justify-content: center, margin: auto, and text-align center, the formatting is still now what I'm looking for. I also know that there must be something that I am missing, but I just don't know what right now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<header className={styles.header}>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.logoaccount}>
  <img></img>
</div>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.searchsearch}>
  <h2>Japanese</h2>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.spacing}></div>
<div className={styles.filters}>
  <button className="location">Location</button>
  <button className="food-type">Food-type</button>
  <button className="rate">Rate</button>
  <button className="apply-filters">Apply-Filters</button>
</div>

*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.header{
text-align: center;
}
.logoaccount{
width: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
margin: auto;
}

.logoaccount > button{
border-radius: 5px;
}

.filters{
width: 75%;
display: flex;
margin: auto;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.filters > button{
width: 15%;
}

.searchsearch{
width: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: auto;
}

.spacing{
height: 20px;
}
```

This is what I get:[image]
[image]

however, I want the second line containing Japanese and "Search" to be centered. I tried all over to look for the solution but I unfortunately couldn't find anything. thanks so much!

Edit: background color for clarification.

Comment: Can you either show us the UI when you highlight the flex div, or provide us a *running* codesandbox of your code that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I tried copy/pasting your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flexbox-with-h2-and-button-63it7) and from what I can tell, the space-between in the flex row is working. I suspect there is more CSS being applied to your elements. Can you create a running codesandbox with your code and CSS so we can inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inspecting the page and using the Select Page Item tool (Ctrl+Shift+C) to see if the problem is visible?. If not, just like you did with .filters > button, try adding the width: 15% style (or try other percentages, like 50%) to the .searchsearch > button. Otherwise, maybe using the filters style instead of the searchsearch one in the div's className changes something that makes it work.